# Order of command line arguments in a Python script

Tags: python

Let's say I  have the following script.

This script finds the largest file under /home and emails the output with the 10 largest files.

```
./myscript.py -d /home -e joe@email.com -p 10
```

Let's say I don't want it to email me, I remove "-e joe@email.com" The script fails because it's expecting "-e" to be present.  I'm assigning the variables via `sys.arg[0] ... sys.arg[1]` and so forth.

Comment: What's the question? Show us some code or something so we can show you the bug.

Comment: Take a look at: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse) or [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse) modules to parse your arguments, instead of parsing them yourself. It allows for optional arguments and you can specify a default value.

Here's a quick example using `optparse`:

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-d", "--directory", metavar="DIR",
    help="Directory to scan for big files")
parser.add_option("-e", "--email", metavar='EMAIL', 
    help='email to send the list to')

opts, args = parser.parse_args()

print 'scanning', opts.directory

if opts.email is None:
    print 'not sending the email'
```

Comment: No dice, we have python 2.4 on most of our servers. :(

Comment: @luckytaxi: added example using optparse which is included on 2.4

Answer (score 3):

Instead of directly assigning arguments to variables via `sys.arg`, why don't you try using the `getopt` or `argparse` modules? It's much easier and more flexible to do so. Here's an example using `argparse` (from the documentation of Python 2.7):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sum or find the max of some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='just an integer')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum command line arguments [default action is to find the maximum]')

args = parser.parse_args() # Simple enough, right?
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

Which you can use (let's call it args.py):

```
# ./args.py 1 2 3 4
4

# ./args.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
10
```

I even changed the order of the integer arguments and the `--sum` and it didn't seem to mind much!

Alternatively, with `getopt`:

```
import getopt, sys

def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hm:v", ["help", "message="])
    except getopt.GetoptError, err:
        print str(err) # will print an error about option not recognized..
        # maybe you should print something informative about correct usage here.
        sys.exit(1)
    # Default option values
    message = None
    verbose = False
    # Process cmd line options
    for o, a in opts:
        if o == "-v":
            verbose = True
        elif o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
            sys.exit(2)
        elif o in ("-m", "--message"):
            message = a
        else:
            assert False, "unhandled option!"
    '''
    Do whatever you wish..
    '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python-2.4 I believe that [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse) is the recommended way to parse command line arguments. It is quite simple to use and it is definitely preferable to parsing options by hand, although it's not as versatile as the newer [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse) module which was introduced in Python-2.7.

EDIT:

Here is a (slightly modified) [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse) snippet from one of my Python programs:

```
options = optparse.OptionParser(description = 'Convert Foo to Bar')

options.add_option('-i', '--input', dest = 'input', action = 'store', default = '-')
options.add_option('-j', '--json', dest = 'json', action = 'store_true', default = False)
options.add_option('-m', '--mongodb', dest = 'mongodb', action = 'store', default = None)
options.add_option('-o', '--output', dest = 'output', action = 'store', default = '-')

(options, argv) = options.parse_args(sys.argv)

if options.json:
    print "output: " + options.output
```